# How to split XML values with nodes in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, xml, nodes

I'm using MySQL version 5.5. I want to split a XML value and insert the values into other table.

Here is my XML:

```
<Xml><Student><Id>1</Id><Marks>275</Marks><Rank>2</Rank></Student></Xml>
```

I want my results became:

```
Id    1
Marks 275
Rank  2
```

Many people suggest that use `ExtractValuefunction` to get the splitted value.

When I use `ExtractValuefunction`, I write queries like below

```
EXTRACTVALUE(Xml,'/Xml/Student/Id') AS ListOfValues
EXTRACTVALUE(Xml,'/Xml/Student/Marks') AS ListOfValues
EXTRACTVALUE(Xml,'/Xml/Student/Rank') AS ListOfValues
```

also I can't get the node values in the results.

How can I get the correct result. Help me to fix this. Thanks in Advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Declare @xmldata text;
set @xmldata = <Xml><Student><Id>1</Id><Marks>275</Marks><Rank>2</Rank></Student></Xml>

SELECT 'Id' AS ColName,EXTRACTVALUE(@xmldata, '/Xml/Student/@Id') AS Val
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Marks', EXTRACTVALUE(@xmldata, '/Xml/Student/@Marks') 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Rank',EXTRACTVALUE(@xmldata, '/Xml/Student/@Rank')
```

Hope this helps you...